check if there is a subarray of length l or smaller with a sum greater than or equal to k
I was trying to solve Leetcode 862. Shortest Subarray with Sum at Least K. My approach was to binary search on a sliding window. So I needed a method which checks for a given length sol, if there exists a subarray of nums with length less than or equal to sol, whos sum is greater than or equal to k. This is the code I wrote to solve that question, and I cannot for the life of me understand why it does not work.
    private static boolean checkSol(int sol, int[] nums, int k){

    long sum = 0;
    int tail = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++){
        sum += nums[i];
        if(tail == i - sol){
            sum -= nums[tail];
            tail++;
        }
        if(sum <= 0){
            sum = 0;
            tail = i+1;
        }
        while(tail <= i && nums[tail] <= 0){
            sum-= nums[tail];
            tail++;
        }
        if(sum >= k){
            System.out.println(i + " " + tail);
            return true;}
    }
    return false;
}

A solution using this code passed most test cases, but failed on some. The one shown had nums.length in the tens of thousands. for sol = 283 it did return true, it also did for sol = 284, all the way to 294. but for sol = 295 or higher it returned false.
I have no idea why as the logic seems valid to me.

I only know that site (or similar) from questions on StackOverflow, some ideas, assuming the logic is correct: time limit exceeded, number overflow, ... kind of hard to guess without some error message

For reference, LeetCode 862 page is https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-subarray-with-sum-at-least-k/description/

Ok, I figured out the reason this fails.
here is an example test case
nums = {4,1,-4,2,2,2,2,-10,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

k = 8;

for sol = 4 this does work, but for sol = 6 it does not work.
To see why the logic fails, consider the window consisting of 4, 1, -4, 2, 2
at this point the 4 and 1 together are worth keeping, since removing them inorder to remove the -4 is not worth it.
if we move 1 to the left we remove 4 and add another 2 so our window looks like
1, -4, 2, 2, 2
in this case it is worth it to drop the 1 so that we can also drop the -4 to shrink our window and make the sum larger.
However in the code, we only shrink the size of the window if the entire sum is negative, or if the left most element is negative. So my code would not shrink the sliding window in this case.

The internet thanks you for returning to reveal the problem.
